# U-boot set default environmental variable

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader

I have an embedded device which:
-I don't have serial console
-I have root console via SSH
-mtd-tools installed, so I can maninpulate /dev/mtdblockX devices which stores bootloader, kernel, etc.

Bootloader is U-boot. I have the full source code for it and I can successfully compile it. I can also set the default environment configs, however the target is not using them - because something has been presetting in the flash for the environment.

I can print them out with fw_printenv. fw_saveenv is not working on this target board.

So my question is:
HOW can I update the u-boot's default env configuration to force it to store it AND overwrite the current ones?

Thanks.

---

**ADDENDUM**

```
#define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND ext4load mmc 0:1 xyz
```

in configs/customboard.h, but after booting and running fw_printenv, it prints "Warning: Bad CRC, using default environment" and a bunch of other strings but not the ext4load which I have defined.

Comment: #define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND ext4load mmc 0:1 xyz in configs/customboard.h, but after booting and running fw_printenv, it prints "Warning: Bad CRC, using default environment" and a bunch of other strings but not the ext4load which I have defined.

Comment: Your post is confusing.  U-Boot doesn't do SSH, so how to you get a command prompt?  *"however the target is not using them"* -- A negative description is incomplete.  Do you know what the variables of the active environment are?  *"because something has been presetting in the flash for the environment"* -- That sounds like a guess on your part rather than a verified observation.  See blue_z's post in https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-embedded-and-single-board-computer-78/u-boot-environment-variable-not-updating-4175646392/